# Authentication error when running python script- pandas GBQ

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have written a python script using python panda gbq to create a table in google big query. However, when i press the token link to authenticate I get this error. Please can someone help me? error 400

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please revisit the [Authentication Method/s](https://googleapis.dev/python/pandas-gbq/latest/howto/authentication.html) you have used for this use case. The  Error 400 basically refers to invalid input which in this case appears to be your [OAuth token](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/error-messages#autherrors) used for access permission.

> Errors thrown by the OAuth token generation system return the following JSON object, as defined by the OAuth2 specification.
>
> `{"error" : "description\\\_string"}`
>
> The error is accompanied by either an HTTP 400 Bad Request error or an HTTP 401 Unauthorized error. description_string is one of the error codes defined by the OAuth2 specification. For example:
>
> `{"error":"invalid\\\_client"}`

Sharing with you this *[Comparison with pandas-gbq](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/pandas-gbq-migration)* document as well for it contains coded samples that can be useful.

I've also noticed in your screenshot that you have shared a [PII](https://support.google.com/a/answer/10985601?hl=en#:%7E:text=Sharing%20PII%20and%20SPII%20with%20Google%20Cloud%20Support) (your email in this case). Kindly remove or hide this information as it can pose a [privacy](https://support.google.com/a/answer/10985601?hl=en) incident. Thank you.

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for the links and my apologies for my email showing in the screenshot ! I removed the screenshot now to prevent privacy issue!!:) I will have a look at these links to help me!!